# Matrix columns correlations, excluding self-correlation, Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

I have a couple of matrices (1800 x 27) that represent subjects and their recordings (3 minutes equivalent for each of 27 subjects).  Each column represents a subject.

I need to do intercorrelation between subjects, let's say to correlate F to G, G to H, and H to F for all 27 subjects.

I use  CORR command  corr(B) where B is a matrix and it returns the next example:

```
1   0.07    -0.05   0.10    0.04    0.12

0.07    1   -0.02   -0.08   0.17    0.03

-0.05   -0.02   1   0.04    0.16    0.13

0.10    -0.08   0.04    1   -0.04   0.34

0.04    0.18    0.16    -0.04   1   0.13
```

How can I adjust the code to exclude self-correlation (eg F to F) so I won't get "1" numerals?
(it's present in each row/column)

I have to perform some transformations afterwards, like  Fisher Z-Transformation, which returns inf for each "1", and as result, I can't use further calculations.

Comment: The diagonal elements are going to be 1 if you use corr. Why don't you replace them with something else after running corr if it is not relevant to your computations later.

Comment: Navan, thank you very much for the reply. I did, I just thought there is a better solution.